# How to make StreamBuilder stop listening for events

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am using a StreamBuilder to access the contents of my Firestore database and create a list of List Tiles for such content. My problem is that whenever I click on a List Tile, it's like my StreamBuilder method gets called again and doubles the amount of List Tiles that I need in my list (since I am using the List.add() method).

How do I make StreamBuilders stop "re-building" or "listening"? I'm fairly new to Dart so I'm not sure how to approach this.

Here is the code that keeps getting repeated. (I have censored some information in places that contain "..." for the purpose of this post):

```
Widget showContent(BuildContext context) {
    var topics = new List();
    var messages = new List();
    var dates = new List();
    List<Widget> content = new List<Widget>();

    return new StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: Firestore.instance.collection("collection-id").snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snap) {
          //just add this line
          if (snap.data == null) return CircularProgressIndicator();

          for (int i = 0; i < snap.data.documents.length; i++) {
            topics.add(...);
            messages.add(snap.data.documents[i]["message"].toString());
            dates.add(...);
          }

          for (var i = 0; i < topics.length; i++) {
            content.add(new Container(
                child: new ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.events, color: Colors.black, size: 30,),
                  title: Text(topics[i].toString()),
                  subtitle: Text(messages[i].toString()),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ReadContent(topics[i], messages[i],dates[i])),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(border: new Border(bottom: new BorderSide()))));
          }//for
          return new Column(children: content);
        });//StreamBuilder
}//showContent()
```

This is a snippet from Stateful widget where showContent() is called:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('App'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: new Container(
          child: new SingleChildScrollView(
            child: new Column(
              children: <Widget>[

                  showContent(context),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
 );//Scaffold
}
```

Comment: Show your approach to this, show your code. It will be helpful to anybody trying to help.

Comment: Please, add your code, so we can check further what it's going on. If you could provide a screenshot from what it's being printed as well, it will help everyone to understand your case.

Comment: Okay, I just updated my question with a snippet of code. Please take a look for me. @gso_gabriel

Comment: Add the `showContent` signature as well

Comment: You don't need the `new` keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't post any code so I will have to guess how your code works.

I assume you are using your `Firebase` `Stream` right inside the `StreamBuilder.stream`, so every time `build` is called this `Firebase` call is being invoked again and again.

`build()` functions are supposed to have no side effects, you should call `Firebase` on `initState()` and save that call as a `Future` or a `Stream` and then use that variable on your `build()` function's `StreamBuilder`. This way the `Future`/`Stream` is only created once.

Again, you didn't post any code, so I am assuming a lot here.

Comment: Okay, I just updated my question with a snippet of code. Please take a look for me.

Comment: Each time your `StreamBuilder` receives and update it will add more items, you need to clean the lists before you fill them.